# glm.project() function showing error even though arguments are of proper type

Tags: python, glm

I am new at `glm` and I am trying to convert 3d object coordinates into window coordinates using `glm.project()` method in pyqt5 GUI.

Here is the code for on mouse press event to convert 3d coordinate into window coordinates.

```py
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.makeCurrent()
        objCoord = glm.vec3(-1,-1,1)
        coord = glm.project(objCoord, self.cube['model']*self.cube['view'], self.cube['projection'], glm.vec4(0,0,self.width, self.height))
        self.doneCurrent()
        print(coord)
```

I am passing proper arguments.

Here you can see arguments used in this.

```py
self.cube['model'] = glm.mat4(1)
```

```py
self.cube['view'] = glm.lookAt(
            glm.vec3(0,0,self.z),
            glm.vec3(0,0,0),
            glm.vec3(0,1,0)
        )
```

```py
self.cube['projection'] = glm.perspective(glm.radians(45), width / height, 2.0, 100.0)
```

but it is showing the following error of invalid arguments types.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openglWidget.py", line 147, in mousePressEvent
    glm.project(objCoord, self.cube['model']*self.cube['view'], self.cube['projection'], glm.vec4(0,0,self.width, self.height))
TypeError: invalid argument type(s) for project()
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am very frustrated by this.

Can anybody help me what is wrong with this code and what can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

`glm.project()` takes 4 arguments vec3(), mat4(), mat4() and vec4() resepectively.

but in the above scenario, 2nd and 3rd arguments are not type of mat4() so these arguments have to be converted into mat4().

It can be done by copying elements one by one from cube['model'] and others to mat4() variable in parts of 4 vec4() variable and then pass that mat4() variable to glm.project().